# content space not set in bottom of the page in jQuery mobile?

Tags: ipad, jquery-mobile

I'm getting white space at bottom of the page in iPad and I use jQuery mobile beta2. I'm splitting the UI as primary and secondary page.
 when I move from first page to second page I'm getting white space in bottom of the iPad. Can any one help me?
Thanks in advance.

code:

```
       <div data-role="page" class="type-interior" id="homePage">
         <div data-role="header"><label> header </label></div>
            <div data-role="content" id="contentHomePage">
                <div class="content-primary">
                    <div data-role="fieldcontain"  data-inset="true" id="search">
                               <div style="width:40em;"><select tabindex="2" name="select-choice-1" class="ui-select" id="searchIn"  data-native-menu="true"></select> 
                               </div>
                     </div>
                </div>

<div class="content-secondary" >
    <div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="true" data-theme="b">
        <ul data-role="listview" id="mainMenuListView" data-theme="a" data-dividertheme="a"></ul> 
    </div>
    </div>
       </div>
</div>      </div>
```

//page:2

```
       <div data-role="page" class="type-interior" id="resultPage">
         <div data-role="header"><label> header </label></div>
            <div data-role="content" id="resultPage">
                <div class="content-primary">
                    <div data-role="fieldcontain"  data-inset="true" id="search">
                               <div style="width:40em;"><select tabindex="2" name="select-choice-1" class="ui-select" id="searchIn"  data-native-menu="true"></select> 
                               </div>
                     </div>
                </div>

<div class="content-secondary" >
    <div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="true" data-theme="b">
        <ul data-role="listview" id="mainMenuListView" data-theme="a" data-dividertheme="a"></ul> 
    </div>
    </div>
       </div>
</div>      </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Her I found solution for this problem. I set content height.

```
.ui-content {
                min-height: 775px;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because your 'content-primary' does not take too much space. You can solve it in few ways, but I guess that the most logic one will be to use media queries (CSS) and to set the div dimensions in your CSS file. For more info: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0b3/docs/api/mediahelpers.html

BTW, You might want to use jQuery mobile Beta 3